# Stata - Spin on Reshape

Tags: formatting, stata, reshape

I was working through reshaping a file and was wondering how Stata handled a file in the below format. Using data from a race, for example.

```
Race_Number      Race_Date    Racer_1_Name     Racer_2_Name     Racer_3_Name Racer_1_Position     Racer_2_Position     Racer_3_Position
```

Is it possible to transform this to the following.

```
Race_Number Race_Date Racer_Name Racer Position
```

Out of curiosity I created the above dataset and `reshape` did not work and I had to manually manipulate.

Comment: As @Roberto Ferrer flags, this is a poor question. Code you do not show us "did not work". Indeed this is off-topic by standard criteria: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (Specifically also, "Race Date" is not a legal variable name.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We appreciate you show us exactly what your input/output was. Things like

> ...`reshape` did not work and I had to manually manipulate.

don't tell us much.

Also, a **complete** toy data set would have helped. I assume you mean `Race_Date` where you typed `Race Date` (first code line) and `Racer_Position` where you typed `Racer Position` (second code line).

You can try

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example dataset -----

input ///
Race_Num Race_Dat str5(R1_Name R2_Name R3_Name) R1_Pos R2_Pos R3_Pos
1 5 "Al" "Bob" "Carl" 3 2 1 
2 7 "Al" "Bob" "Carl" 3 1 2 
3 15 "Al" "Bob" "Carl" 1 2 3
end

format Race_Dat %td
list

*----- what you want -----

forvalues i = 1/3 {
    rename R`i'_Name Nam_R`i'
    rename R`i'_Pos Pos_R`i'
}

list

reshape long Pos_R Nam_R, i(Race_Num) j(Racer)

order Race_Num Race_Dat
list, sepby(Race_Num)
```

All I did was change variable names before the `reshape`.

A better way is to use the `@` and then there's no need for renaming variables:

```
reshape long R@_Pos R@_Name, i(Race_Num) j(Racer)
```